# Error in app.module.ts after on adding AngularMultiSelectModule

Tags: angular, dropdown, multi-select

I'm using **angular version 6** and am trying to integrate **angular2-multiselect-dropdown** in my app. On trying to run the app, after following the usage steps from this reference:
http://cuppalabs.github.io/components/multiselectDropdown/
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-multiselect-dropdown

I get error as below:

```
Date: 2019-05-02T07:41:56.573Z
Hash: 8b7ca08bfd8ad516f706
Time: 27855ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 4.99 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 473 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 5.22 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 158 kB [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 255 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 7.43 MB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve "angular2-multiselect- 
dropdown/angular2-multiselect-dropdown" in 
"D:\Projects\Gosnow\src\gosnow_admin\src\app"
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

I also tried with angular2-multiselect-dropdown: **4.2.2** and angular2-multiselect-dropdown: **4.2.0** both to get the same error.

May I please get some help on this?

Comment: It looks like you are using the wrong import statement, the right import for this module is `import { AngularMultiSelectModule } from 'angular2-multiselect-dropdown';`

Comment: I used your import `angular2-multiselect- 
dropdown/angular2-multiselect-dropdown` when i installed the version 2.10.2 of angular2-multiselect-dropdown. maybe it will help you

Comment: Thanks @MichalS, this removed the compilation error and I'm able to use the library now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The import statement in the documentation here http://cuppalabs.github.io/components/multiselectDropdown/#Usage is incorrect.

```
import { AngularMultiSelectModule } from 'angular2-multiselect-dropdown/angular2-multiselect-dropdown';
```

should be

```
import { AngularMultiSelectModule } from 'angular2-multiselect-dropdown';
```